# When I upload any media file it says "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2017/04"

Tags: media

Please help if any one can.I tried it to create uploads folder manually and then upload media in upload folder but then i can not get my media file in WordPress dashboard media file.

Comment: This might be due to server permission. Did you check the permissions of upload folder

Comment: yes permission is 7 5 5..

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem due to permissions.

You will need to change your files permission's in your upload folder (2017/04 in my case) to drwxdrwx.

Answer (score 0):

If the permission is 755 which is correct then.

Check if the upload folder user-group is apache/httpd ( or Any user-group who has access to your website root folder ).

Answer (score 0):

You can run a command through terminal if you have access to the server shell, run it from the root website folder:

```
sudo chmod g+w wp-content/uploads -R
```